# Powershell -parallel and thread safe usage?

Tags: powershell

6 hours later and I am getting closer. Started learning Visual Studio Code vs ISE so I can easily use PowerShell 7.  Learned about -Parallel, then how you can't call variables in the Script Block without using $using:. (That took forever!) Tried the -Asjob part but that doesn't seem right for this.  I am basically taking a text file with 20 lines and search for matches in a 300k+ lines of a CSV.

I believe I have gotten to a part I just can't figure out. I think I need to know how to use "thread safe" objects based upon the error.

```
$textfile = "C:\test_delete\key_words.txt"
$loglocation = "C:\test_delete\datablob.csv"
$outputfile = "C:\test_delete\test5.csv"

New-Item -Path $outputfile

Get-Content $textfile | ForEach-Object -Parallel {
    Select-String  -Raw -Path $using:loglocation -Pattern $_ |
    Out-File -append $using:outputfile
}
```

**Error**
Out-File: 
Line |
   3 |      Out-File -append $using:outputfile
     |      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | The process cannot access the file 'C:\test_delete\test5.csv' because it is being used by another process.

In the ForEach-Object help, Example 11, it talks about thread safe usage and the example declares the variable = the thread safe syntax.  That makes sense (kinda).  Except in this case, I am wanting to eventually have a paramenter declared for $outfile which will need to be called in a tread safe manner. I am getting ahead of myself but just can't figure out how to make that thread safe call to $outfile.

Sorry for be verbose, this is my first post and just want to relay I have spent some time trying to get this.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: have you thot about what detailed steps you are coding? it LOOKS like you are ... [A] sending one line of the text file to the pipeline. [B] loading the ENTIRE CSV and searching it for that one line [out of 20]. that loads the file 20 times! [C] sending any matches to your output file. ///// wouldn't it make more sense to load the target file ONCE and then compare the file to the entire set of "match these" lines? the `Get-Content` cmdlet has a `-ReadCount` parameter that lets you tell it to send stuff thru the pipeline in chunks ... [*grin*]

Comment: I never thought about sending one line of text. That's a great idea. I had not thought about that. My current error though is writing to the output.

Comment: The problem is writing to the same file from different threads.  Can you put the | out-file outside the foreach?

Comment: @Berry - the output problem is caused by making the file access INSIDE of your pipeline. instead, assign the pipeline output to a $Var & use that to do your writes after the fact. ///// if your results get too large for your available RAM, you can take a look at thread-safe file access using mutex ideas.

Answer (score 2):

Here's my preferred alternative - **don't use `ForEach-Object -Parallel` here, it's unecessary**:

```
Select-String -Path $loglocation -Pattern (Get-Content $textfile) | Out-File $outputfile -Append
```

That's it, you're done, no need to worry about concurrent write access :)

---

*If you still insist, below are a couple of examples of how to handle this specific example.*

The "thread-safe" dictionary assignment in the help file works because the data type in question (`ConcurrentDictionary<string,object>`) is implemented with thread safety in mind.

If you want to write to a file in a thread safe manner, you'll need to maintain a lock or a mutex manually:

```
$fileLock = [System.Threading.ReaderWriterLockSlim]::new()

Get-Content $textfile | ForEach-Object -Parallel {
    $lock = $using:fileLock
    try{
        $lock.EnterWriteLock()
        Select-String -Raw -Path $using:loglocation -Pattern $_ |
        Out-File -Append $using:outputfile
    }
    finally{
        if($lock.IsWriteLockHeld){
            $lock.ExitWriteLock()
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively, move the write operations outside the parallel loop:

```
Get-Content $textfile | ForEach-Object -Parallel {
    Select-String -Raw -Path $using:loglocation -Pattern $_
} | Out-File -Append $outputfile
```

Comment: Thank you Mathias!  I appreciate you taking the time to provide solutions even when you didn't feel the extra effort was worth it.  I ended up using your second alternative, I had to edit it and take off the $using from the Out-File line.  Due to the size of some of the searches, I had hoped to see if the -Parallel would reduce the search time.  Using use -Process it was taking on average 2 min 57 seconds, with your solution it cut the time to 85 seconds!  Thanks again! I need to learn more about System Threading.

Comment: Well, this project was a slight fail so far.  While searching -Parallel vs -Process is definetly faster.  Side by side testing with "findstr"....findstr is faster. :(

Comment: @Berry Try adding `-SimpleMatch` to `Select-String`